# Python Socket --> Send/Receive messages at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have been working on a simple project using socket and thread. 
My problem is that i have a lot of threads, i would like to make a thread sending message to another thread, in the same time the thread receive a lot of message from a client how i do this and thanks. 
this is my functions for client and for server

```
     def client(self,addr, port,msg):
            print("capteur with addr ", self.addr, "connecting to :", addr)

            conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            conn.bind((self.addr, self.port))
            conn.connect((addr, port))

            conn.send(str.encode(str(msg)))

            '''data = conn.recv(2048)
            print('data received from server', addr, ':',data.decode('utf-8'))'''
            conn.close()
#methode serveur 
    def server(self):

            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            try:
                s.bind((self.addr, self.port))
            except socket.error as e:
                print(str(e))
            s.listen(len(self.listvoisin_cellule))
            print('Capteur',self.addr, 'of port',self.port,'Waiting for a connection.\n')
            while True:

                try:
                    conn, ad = s.accept()
                except socket.timeout as e:
                    print(str(e))
                    s.close()
                    return

                print('client : '+ad[0]+':'+str(ad[1]),' connected')
                data = conn.recv(2048)
                print('data received from client', ad[0],':', ad[1],' is :', data.decode('utf-8'))

                strData= data.decode('utf-8')
                infos= strData.split(',')
                a=float(infos[0])
                self.listdistance.append(a)
                conn.close()
            s.close()
```

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve] if you want us to show you how to adapt your code. Otherwise, you're basically asking for someone to write you a tutorial—one that won't be as good as the zillions that are always available online, being written on the fly, and that may not be easy to adapt to the way you've actually organized your code.

Comment: i have adding a image description

Comment: help me to lets the thread be server and client in the same time

Comment: Why do they have to be in the same thread, instead of having separate threads? If you really want them to be in the same thread, you need to handle async in some other way, like `asyncio` or `selectors` in the stdlib, or a third-party library like Twisted or Monocle. Stack Overflow is not a good place to get recommendations for one of those over the others, and it's also not a good place to get a tutorial for whichever one you pick, but that's what you need here.

Comment: Also, as written, your server can only handle one client at a time. Is that OK for your use case? If not, you need to add per-connection threads to the server (at which point there's even less reason not to have the client in a separate thread), or you need to rewrite the whole thing around asyncio or a manual selector or…

Comment: i have the problem : [Errno 98] Address already in use/
of course i have 2 threads the first  thread is a server with his address and the second he want to send a msg for a another server, what can i do to let the thread send a msg but another thread use this address for server